# How can a renamed file's path remain unchanged in java?

Tags: java, rename

So I finally changed the name of `file1` to another name. However what makes me frustrated is that the path remain unchanged!Could you please tell me why and how to deal with it since I always need the handler of file1 for further operation?Here is my sample code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestFile {
volatile private static File file1;
volatile private static File file2;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    file1 = new File("D:\\work\\triangle\\src\\original\\test1.java");
    file2 = new File("D:\\work\\triangle\\src\\original\\test2.java");
    File tmpFile;

    String file2name = file2.getAbsolutePath().toString().replace("\\", "/") + ".bak";
    System.out.println(file2name);

    String file1name = file1.getAbsolutePath().toString()
            .replace("\\", "/");
    System.out.println(file1name);

    tmpFile = new File(file2name);
    if (!file1.renameTo(tmpFile)) {
        System.err.println("file1->file2name-bak");
    }
    System.out.println("file1\t"+file1.getAbsolutePath().toString());
    System.out.println("tmpFile\t"+tmpFile.getAbsolutePath().toString());

}
}
```

and I get those output:

```
D:/work/triangle/src/original/test2.java.bak
D:/work/triangle/src/original/test1.java
file1   D:\work\triangle\src\original\test1.java
tmpFile D:\work\triangle\src\original\test2.java.bak
```

How can the `file1` and `tmpFile` yield different path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what a `File` is.

A `File` denotes a file name / path, not the name / path of a *specific* file.  So, when you use a `File` to rename a file, the pathname stored in your `File` object does not change.  A `File` object is immutable.

> Then is there any way to change them both?

No.  The name / path encoded in a `File` object does not change, and cannot be changed.  If you don't believe me, check the source code that is shipped with your JDK.

(The pathname state of a `File` is represented by the String-valued `path` attribute.  The only places where `path` is assigned are the constructors, and the `readObject` method.)

Comment: Then is there any way to change them both?

Comment: It seems not what you said since `file1.getName()` is **test1.java**,not **test2.java.bak**

Comment: I think you need to explain what you are trying to accomplish in more detail. It will be easier to help then.

Comment: @WilliamSeemann Actually there is a need to exchange the name of file `test1.java` and `test2.java` now and then.